# Isomorphism ${}^*P\otimes_A P \cong {}_A\text{End}(P)$ for $P$ finitly generated and projective.

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

Let $P \in {}_A \text{Mod}$ be a left $A$-module for $A$ a ring and ${}^*P = {}_A\text{Hom}(P, A)$ the dual which is a right $A$-module for the action defined by
$$fa(p):= f(ap).$$
If $P$ is finitly generated and projective, we can show that ${}^*P\otimes_A P$ is a ring with the unit given by
$$\sum_{i = 1}^nf_i \otimes e_i,$$
where $(e_i, f_i)_{i= 1}^n$ is a finite dual base for $P$. In my course, my teacher said that, for $P$ finitly generated and projective, the previous tensor product is canonically isomorphic to ${}_A\text{End}(P)$ and the isomorphism is given by
$$f:{}^*P\otimes_A P \to {}_A\text{End}(P): f\otimes_A p \mapsto (f(\cdot)p:p' \mapsto f(p')p).$$
But here is my problem: this map does not seem well-defined. For $a\in A$,
$$(fa\otimes_A p)(p') = fa(p')p = f(ap')p = af(p')p$$
and
$$(f\otimes_A ap)(p') = f(p')ap$$
which is not the same when $A$ is not commutative. Where is the mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong action of $A$ on the dual. When you compute $\text{Hom}_A(P, A)$ you've "used up" the left action of $A$ on $P$ already so your left multiplication definition doesn't work; if you check carefully you'll find that $f(ap)$ is not $A$-linear in general. The correct $A$-module structure comes from the $(A, A)$-bimodule structure on $A$, which is to say concretely that the correct action is

$$(fa)(p') = f(p') a$$

and then there's no problem. Of course when $A$ is commutative everything is a bimodule and then your definition is equivalent to this one.

Comment: Ok, so the mistake comes from the definition of the left action "$fa(p) := f(ap)$"?

Comment: @Falcon: you mean the right action, and yes, that's what I said.